# Symfony 2 functional tests: bypassing ssl

Tags: php, symfony, ssl

I am using an authenticated user to test a login page that doesn't use the shibboleth provider from the prod environment. However on running the test, I seem to be getting a 500 http status. Here's the config:

> security_test.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        test:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/apps
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Area"
            provider: test
```

---

> ControllerTest.php

```
class GenerateResetcodeControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    private $client = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    /**
     * @group debug
     */
    public function testGenerateResetCodeAction()
    {

        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/apps/resetcode', array(), array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'adminpass',
        ));
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

---

> app/logs/test.log

```
[2015-03-24 11:15:54] app.CRITICAL: SSL connect error [] []
[2015-03-24 11:15:54] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Util\XMLApiCallerBundle\Call\XMLApiCallerException: "System Unavailable" at /var/www/src/AccountServicesBundl
e/Services/AccountServiceRest.php line 149 {"exception":"[object] (Util\\XMLApiCallerBundle\\Call\\XMLApiCallerException(code: -1): System Unavailable at /var/www/src/AccountServicesBundle/Services/AccountServiceRest.php:149)"} []
```

Is there any way I can bypass SSL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to bypass secure connection. Try this:

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/apps/resetcode', array(), array(),
    array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'adminpass',
        'HTTPS' => true
    )
);
```

or

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient(array(), array('HTTPS' => true));
}
```

It should issue HTTPS request. If you really want to bypass SSL you can maybe create routing_test.yml for test enviroment and override routes definition but it depends on way how you force https restriction.

Comment: I tried with HTTPS and I still get the same message. Something is wrong with the configuration. Is there any place I could narrow this down?

Comment: Are you sure your problem is really in SSL? Try to remove HTTPs restriction and run tests again on HTTP. Do you have in prod conf secured_area key under firewalls? You can also look at `src/AccountServicesBundle/Services/AccountServiceRest.php` on line 149. Why exception is thrown? It is really hard to say where is real problem :-(.